# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i, ora-12560

[image]

I Google[d] for this error **ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error** but not able to find the actual reason and how to solve this error ?

Can anyone tell me a perfect solution to solve login problem.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

1. Go to the windows machine that hosts the Oracle database server
2. Go to Start -> Run -> Services.msc in Windows.
   Locate *OracleService < SID >* (here `OracleServiceORCL`) and click on `Start` to start the oracle database service (if not already running)
   [image: Services]
3. Once it is up and running, from the command prompt run the following:

   ```
   tnsping < tnsalias >
   ```

   (*tnsalias* entry you can find it in `tnsnames.ora` file)

Comment: In my case service is running but again this error ? what should i do?

Comment: So, this assumes you are running Oracle Server on Windows?

Comment: I use Oracle 11g on Windows 8.1 . Before all, I set `ORACLE_SID`. `sqlplus` works, no problem, then I close it. I reopen, I try many times, but not working. Even, when service is running, `sqlplus` doesn't work.

Comment: I am using windows 8 and oracle 12c. Instead of "OracleServiceORCL" i have found "OracleServiceORACLE12C". I have just started it and i have to not run the command. Ur answer is very useful.

Comment: Worked for me :)

Comment: I am on WIndows 10 with Oracle 11g. The service I had to start was `OracleServiceXE`. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 50):

In my case I didn't have an `OracleService` (OracleServiceORCL) in Windows `Services.msc` as described in [Bharathi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904462/114029).

I executed this command:

```
C:\> ORADIM -NEW -SID ORCL
```

and then the `OracleService` called OracleServiceORCL just showed up and got started in Services.msc. Really nice.

---

Source: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=4044655#4044655

Comment: You really saved me, I stuck in this issue for months. Since I have vpn I was able to work on the server. I really wanted to configure on local you helped me. Thanks

Comment: I get: ORADIM is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Hey @Diego: this may help you: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2209100/oradim-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 30):

Seems like database is not up. It might be due to restarting machine and the instance is not set to autostart and it so not started munually after starting from services Screen.

Just goto Command prompt

1. Set Oracle SID
   **C:>set oracle_sid=ORCL**
2. Now run **Net start** command.
   **C:>net start oracleserviceORCL**

Comment: As Tom also suggests here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adapter-error-200709. In 2018, this would apply to your docker container, virtualbox image, etc.

Answer (score 17):

from command console, if you get this error you can avoid it by typing

```
c:\> sqlplus /nolog
```

then you can connect

```
SQL> conn user/pass @host:port/service
```

Answer (score 14):

Add to the environment vars the following variable and value to identify the place of the `tnsnames.ora` file:

TNS_ADMIN

C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\admin

Comment: You may also need to set ORACLE_HOME to something like C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1

Answer (score 11):

In my case (for OracleExpress) the service was running, but I got this issue when trying to access the database via sqlplus without connection identifier:

```
sqlplus sys/mypassword as sysdba
```

To make it work I needed to add the connection identifier (XE for Oracle Express), so following command worked ok:

```
sqlplus sys/mypassword@XE as sysdba
```

If you still get ORA-12560, make sure you can ping the XE service. Use:

```
tnsping XE
```

And you should get OK message along with full connection string (tnsping command is located in oracle's installation dir: [oracle express installation dir]\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin). If you can not ping make sure your `tnsnames.ora` file is reachable for sqlplus. You might need to set TNS_ADMIN environment variable pointing to your ADMIN directory, where the file is located, for example:

```
TNS_ADMIN=[oracle express installation dir]\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN
```

Answer (score 7):

After searching alot got a simple way to solve it.
Just follow the steps.

1. Check status of your listener.

   1. open command prompt and type `lsnrctl status`
   2. You will get no listener.
2. Now open `listener.ora` file which is present in following directory: `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN`

   1. Open that file and change the host parameter with you computer name
   2. You can get your computer name by right click on `My Computer` and check you computer name, and replace host parameter with your computer name as follows:

      `LISTENER =
           (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
               (DESCRIPTION =
                   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
                   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Electron-PC)(PORT = 1521)
               )
           )
      )`

      So here you can observe `HOST = Electron-PC`, which is my computer name.
   3. Save the listener.ora file and again return to cammand propt

   3.Type the following in command prompt `lsnrctl start`

This will start the `OracleTNSListner`.

you can check it in the service by opening services tab of Task Manager. if not started automatically you can start it.

Just this much and you are ready to work again on oracle.

Best of Luck.

Comment: Don't forget to change `tnsnames.ora` file too!

Answer (score 3):

Quite often this means that the listener hasn't started.  Check the Services panel.

On Windows (as you are) another common cause is that the ORACLE_SID is not defined in the registry.  Either edit the registry or set the ORACLE_SID in a CMD box.  (Because you want to run sqlplusw.exe I suggest you edit the registry.)

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem the easy way. My oracle was running just fine in the past. After I installed MS SQL Server was when I noticed this problem. I just uninstalled MS SQL Server on my machine then the problem was gone. Make sure you restart your computer after that. Now I can connect to Oracle database through SQLPlus again. My guess is that there's some conflict between the two. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution that just worked for me...considering I was using my local login as the dba permissions.

Follow the steps to get to Services.  Right click on the instance and go to 'Log On'? (might not be the name but it's one of the tabs containing permissions).  Change the settings to use LOCAL.

Answer (score 1):

If none the above work, then try this :
Modify the `LISTENER.ora` (mine is found in : `oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora`) ==> add a custom listener that points to your database(SID), example my SID is XZ0301, so :

```
## Base XZ03001

SID_LIST_LISTENER_XZ03001=(SID_LIST=(SID_DESC=(ORACLE_HOME =
E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)(SID_NAME= XZ03001)))

LISTENER_XZ03001=(DESCRIPTION_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL =
TCP)(HOST=MyComputerName)(PORT= 1521)))

DIAG_ADR_ENABLED_LISTENER_XZ03001=ON

ADR_BASE_LISTENER_XZ03001=E:\oracle
```

Restart your machine

For Windows 7, use the following to modify the LISTENER.ora:
 - Go to Start > All Programs > Accessories
 - Right click Notepad and then click Run as Administrator .
 - File>open and navigate to the tnsnames.ora file.
 - Make the changes then it should allow you to save

Answer (score 1):

It really has worked on my machine. But instead of OracleServiceORCL I found OracleServiceXE.

Answer (score 1):

Flow the flowing steps :

1. Edit your listener.ora and tnsnames.ora file in 
   $Oracle_home\product\11.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN location

   a. add listener.ora file

   ```
   LISTENER =
     (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
       (DESCRIPTION =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
   ```

   )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C: [here c is oralce home directory]

b. add in tnsnames.ora file

```
    SCHEMADEV =
            (DESCRIPTION =
                     (ADDRESS_LIST =
                     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dabase_ip)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = SCHEMADEV)
    )
  )
```

2. Open command prompt and type 
   sqlplus username/passowrd@oracle_connection_alias

Example : 
username : your_database_username
          password : Your_database_password
          oracle_connection_alias : SCHEMADEV  for above example.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up, follow the screenshot and choose local account to start if not selected. Then start the service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell SQLPlus which database you want to log on to.  Host String needs to be either a connection string or an alias configured in your TNSNames.ora file.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12560: TNS:erro de adaptador de protocolo

1. set Environment Variables: ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID
2. make sure your user is part of ORACLE_GROUP_NAME (Windows)
3. make sure the file ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora is:
   SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
4. (Windows) Be carefull when you add a new Oracle client: adding a new path to the PATH env. variable can mess things up. The first entry in this variable makes a difference: certify that the sqlplus executable in the ORACLE_HOME (ORACLE_HOME/bin) comes first in the PATH env. variable.

Answer (score 0):

I try 2 option:

1. You change service OracleService in Service Tab -> Running
2. Login with cmd command: sqlplus user_name/pass_word@orcl12C
   Note: orcle12c -> name of OracleService name run in you laptop

Answer (score 0):

Below fixes can be applied to resolve `TNS 12560` error

1. Get Latest patch for `SQL*NET` client software
2. Set `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$PATH` variable (should be accessible for System user)
3. Check permissions on PC client
4. Check `$TNS_ADMIN` variable
5. Check if network has firewall or antivirus issues
6. Check if windows services Run >> Services.msc has OracleXE or OracleORCL service running
   Check below link in case of net tracing error:

http://dba-oracle.com/t_sql_net_tracing.htm

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was having both C:\Oracle\tns_admin\ and C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\ on my laptop. I renamed C:\Oracle to C:\Oracle-DISABLE to fix the error and being able to work with sqlplus from the commandline again to manage my Oracle XE installation.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, (**ORA-12560: TNS protocol adapter error**)Issue cause of database connection issue like database, user name and password.

Once you got the issue. Initially you have to **check connection details**, after check the oracle service and further more.

I missed some connection details, So only i got **TNS protocol adapter error**, 
***I will changed the connection details, It would be working fine***.