# ORA-12560:TNS:Protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error)

When I try to login to the database, I am geting this error.

> ORA-12560:TNS:Protocol adapter error

Can anyone please guide me about it?

I am using windows 7, Oracle 11.2.0.2.0.

Comment: Have you had a look at the other questions about this? Did any of them help you? Those that have been answered all provided _a lot_ more information. You've just said you're getting an error.

Comment: Did you provide SID/Service name when you login?

Comment: @Ben,wallyk,Polppan. thanks all of you. problem solved. just visiting wallyk " ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error " thread.

Comment: Please check your oracle services, go to start Start >> Run >> type "services.msc"

OR

IN command line interface
you can start oracle listener with this command 'lsnrctl start'.