# How to unlock an sqlplus user?

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlplus

I am using the following command to login to the DB server: **sqlplus admin/admin@tstdb1**

It was working fine till last night.

But now it is giving the error saying **ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked**

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to the database as system user

```
C:>sqlplus sys/sys@tstdb1 as sysdba
```

and execute the following command in SQL prompt

```
ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to unlock!

1- Open SQL Plus

2- Login as SYSDBA

```
SQL> conn /as sysdba
```

3- Unlock the account

```
SQL> ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

To lock the account

```
SQL> ALTER USER username ACCOUNT LOCK;
```

Comment: Error again.. :( **C:\Users\ep_user>sqlplus SYSDBA/SYSDBA

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Apr 15 23:46:55 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error**

Comment: are both OS Services for the listener & database started & running?

Comment: yeah.. both are running.. :)

Comment: for 12560 error kindly check `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error`

Comment: Service name is unavailable...:(

Answer (score 0):

Following statement may solve your problem, but make sure to execute this using some admin account.

```
ALTER USER USER_NAME 
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD_HERE;

ALTER USER USER_NAME ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Replace USER_NAME and PASSWORD_HERE with your desired values.