# passing connection object into another class through global fails (PHP)

Tags: php, oracle, joomla, joomla3.0

Changing the question in the hope of success...

I have an `oracleDB` class that begins...

```
class oracleDB {
  private $connec, $affectedRows, $parseStatement; 
  public $err;

  function __construct($user,$pwd,$db){
    $this->connec = OCILogon($user, $pwd, $db);
    if ( ! $this->connec ) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function parse($sql){
    $operation = strtolower(substr(ltrim($sql), 0, 6));
    //update and delete must have where clause
    if($operation == "update" || $operation == "delete"){
      if(!stripos($sql, "where")){
        $this->err = "Update or delete query with no where clause!";
          return false;
        }
    }

    $this->parseStatement = oci_parse($this->connec, $sql);
    if ($this->parseStatement){
      var_dump($this->parseStatement);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }//parse
}
```

I can connect to oracle and get data back using a simple connect string and `select *` statement.

However when i pass the connection to a variable

`$conn_test = new OracleDB($user,$pwd,$db);`

and then use and `include('somefile.php');`

and another class

```
class SomeOtherClass{

   function somemethod() {
     global $conn_test;

     $sql='select * from foobar';

     $conn_test->parse($sql);

     //...
   }
}
```

I get a fatal error on parse (on a non object)

`$conn_test` appears to lose it's value (is NULL) and i can't parse my query / return data

- I have tried passing the $conn_test into the method as a variable, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Why this error appears?

Comment: Check this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error

Comment: yes i had read that, but i can connect to oracle and get data back, so not sure this applies in this instance. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of dressing on your question - but what it boils down to is that you created an instance of an object and then were unable to access that instance.

Did you create the object in the global context? I suspect not.

Try changing

```
 $conn_test = new OracleDB($user,$pwd,$db);
```

to...

```
 global $conn_test;
 $conn_test = new OracleDB($user,$pwd,$db);
```

This also rather implies flaws in your diagnosis; there are [subtle differences](http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/) between isset(), isnull() and empty() and the stringified output of undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you **sure** that `$conn_test` is defined? Before the class declaration, check it via `echo isset($conn_test) && $conn_test instanceof OracleDB`. This just to make sure that it was not defined inside of a function/class, which wouldn't give it the visibility you want.

If it IS there, you can try accessing it via `$GLOBALS['conn_test']`. It may also be possible that some other logic is unsetting your variable.