# Failed to login into Oracle 10g

Tags: sql

Although the installation was successful, i have been trying to log in SQLPlus since 3 days. I've seen queries regarding Oracle 10 g log in on this site and elsewhere. Nothing worked. I tried logging  in:

1. using sys, system, sysman, dbsnmp as usernames with and/or without password. (I had set a common password "tiger" during installation for all users)
2. through command prompt typing "sys/as sysdba". But it asks for the password, and again shows a failure message.
3. tried logging in with username "system" and password "manager".

The message that appears each time: ORA-12560: TNS protocol adapter error

I have windows 7 32-bit OS. And i tried the right-click drop-down menu's Properties option to change the setting : Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows 98/ Windows ME as well as for Windows 7.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

1. I tried starting the service from Services.msc, the OracleServiceORCL when started, shows "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly."
2. I could set the SID to ORCL at command prompt(however, it was already named so during installation). But the Net Start command is unrecognized.
3. Leniel's idea(as on the page : [ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error) ) too did not work with my pc.
4. The environment variables have in the PATH all the pathnames required in Oracle. Plus, I also added a TNS_ADMIN variable .
5. Could you please tell what the Host String could be? While trying to login, I leave it blank.

Comment: Is the database service/daemon started?

Comment: http://itbloggertips.com/2013/11/fixed-ora-12560-tns-protocol-adapter-error/

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error)