# Oracle client server connectivity issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, tnsnames

I have installed multiple oracle (homes) clients on my server including 10g and 11g .  When using SQL PLUS 11G client I am getting error "TNS:protocol adapter error." 
I checked TNSNAMES.ora to resolve the issue. I found that  TNSNAMES.ora in the network/admin directory for 11G home is having some values which is identical to a different tnsnames.ora on a different server from which I am successfully able to connect to the server. 
I also get to know about a default TNSNAMES.ora for the entire system but not sure where I can find it. 
I tried tnsping orcl but got error "TNSPING is not recognized as an internal or external command". 
I am new to Oracle, please help

Comment: The first thing to do would be to ensure that the services for the database and listener are up and running.

Comment: You'll probably find a solution in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error) link. I guess this question can be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Rahul but my case is a bit different. I cannot see the service oracleserviceorcl in services.  Is this because of improper setup of the client s/w. The os which I m using is windows server 2003 32bit.

Comment: The Oracle services are configured on the server machine that hosts the database. The client installation will not create a service. What you're seeing is right. Check the services on the server machine.