# Not able to access oracle database on other computer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracleclient

I have two machine(PC1 and PC2).

I want to access oracle database from PC1 to PC2.

I have installed `oracle 11g database` on PC1. and `oracle 11g client(Admin)` on other machine PC2.

For accessing database on PC2 I have done following things:

- Update `tnsname.ora` file - location E:\app\IT\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin
- Entry into path variable `E:\app\IT\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin`
- Restart PC2.

Start `sql Plus` from `oracle-oraClient11g_home -> Application Development -> sql plus`

Sql plus get start after providing user name and password that gives an error-

EORROR:

ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error.

I am try this form last 2 days but still this error occurred.

Please Some body help me for solving this issue.

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error) will help. As a last resort I'd suggest re-installing the server

Comment: Rahul thank you for reply. I follow above link but there no OracleServiceORCL service available in my machine.

Comment: Yes I have found  OracleServiceORCL on PC1 and its already Started.But what should I do in PC2.

Comment: Ok then, if this link worked for few people then it must work for me,let me try from beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of following things:

1. Check your `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$PATH` variables.
2. Check for the permissions on client PC. Make sure firewall is allowing connections.
3. Ensure `TNS_ADMIN` is set properly.
4. Make sure `Oracle Service` is started in the pc where you installed `Oracle 11g`. Verify the `SID`is configured and set.
5. (Important one) Make sure Listener is started on server PC. Just fire `lsnrctl status` to check it.

Comment: I have checked above thing.all I have done perfectly expecting one thing,which is firewall now I have done it,finally able to connect DB.thank you so much.