# Oracle 10g users are expired

Tags: database, oracle10g, sqlplus, ora-12560

I have an Oracle 10g database which is connected to another server with instance client. Problem is all of users(SYS/SYSTEM/SYSMAN/FATASAN/JAVAHER) are expired (I forgot to change expire date) and also sqlpus and instance client are faced with ORA-12560 error (Both servers were good but now I have no connection to data!)

How can I login into my own database when all usernames are expired ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to database server as the Oracle software owner (or, in case of Windows, as user who is member of ORA_DBA group), set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID environment variables, then login as:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

You should get logged in without having to provide a password.

Comment: Thanks I also need this answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error

// Database service needs to be restarted :

Just goto Command prompt

Set Oracle SID C:>set oracle_sid=ORCL

Now run Net start command. C:>net start oracleserviceORCL