# ORA-12560 TNS protocol adapter error

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, oracle12c, ora-12560

I have installed both Oracle 12c and Oracle Client on Windows 8.1. The database was working fine until I installed Oracle Client Software alongwith Oracle Development tool for VS2013 as I wanted to develop a C# application that connected to Oracle database.However after I installed it I'm getting this error.
When I type the following `sqlplus / as sysdba` in cmd I get the following error:

```
ERROR
ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error
```

I followed the steps on this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error)

I Googled a lot and it seems that these are maybe interfering with each other.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Database installation comes with client software too. So, what is the reason to do client-only installation again?

Comment: I wanted the development tools for VS2013 and along with it I installed Oracle client

Comment: Show us how exactly are you connecting to the 12c database.

Answer (score 0):

Most common issues:

- You just installed Oracle 12c database and you are yet to perform the mandatory post-installation steps.
- You want to connect remotely, but actually trying to connect to local instance, i.e. you are not mentioning the SID explicitly.
- The environment variables are not properly set.
- Last, but not the least, the database is not up.

As you have tagged Oracle 12c, I suggest you to first complete the mandatory post-installation steps. See **[Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps.](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/)**

---

**UPDATE** Based on comments, OP has updated the question.

> When I type the following sqlplus / as sysdba in cmd I get the following error:

You are connecting to the **CDB** and not to the **PDB**. As I have already mentioned [here](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/),

The most common misunderstanding is about “`SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA`” usage.

Since we have checked the option to create database as a **CDB**, the “`SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA`” command will always connect to the `CDB`.

So, you need to login as **sysdba** into **PDB** explicitly.

For example,

```
sqlplus SYS/password@PDBORCL AS SYSDBA
```

where `pdborcl` is the **pluggable database**.

Comment: @shawshank Ok, then you need to prove it. How would I or anyone else know what you did? Show us how are you connecting to the database.

Comment: I actually can't log in now so I can't prove it

Comment: @shawshank Do you have access to the database server? Are you the DBA?

Comment: @shawshank You need to show what you are doing just like I have demonstrated in the link I provided. It is as simple as copy paste of your SQL*Plus session.