# Can't connect with instance

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

i have two oracle SID's orcl and catdb. I can connect with catdb but can't connect orcl. I am connecting sqlplus as sysdba and i get

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

What possible reasons maybe here?

Comment: How are you attempting to connect?

Comment: Please update the question accordingly with the command/code you are using and the response you get back. We can't help you much here because there can be a lot going on

Comment: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error

Comment: Thanks!! it worked  :)