# How to connect to Oracle DB without OracleService*?

Tags: windows, oracle

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904462/3395831) answer states that we should start `OracleService*` in order to connect to an Oracle DB.

However, there isn't a `OracleService*` among the list shown by `services.msc`.

Is there any other way to connect to an Oracle DB from command line, without using `OracleService*`?

Comment: I don't think you can start an Oracle instance on Windows without the service. But try `sqlplus / as sysdba` then use `startup` and see what happens. You probably need to start the listener for that (`lsnrctl start`)

Comment: The problem is, there is no `lsnrctl` in `PATH` as well. Where is it located, so that maybe I can add it to `PATH`?

Comment: `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nope. No `lsnrctl` as well.

Comment: Then you have corrupted/incomplete installation. You can't have a properly  installed Oracle without the listener or the listener control tool.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We use Toad. So I guess Toad does not use the listener in order to connect?

Comment: All connections to an Oracle database channel through a TNS Listener process.The Listener acts as the broker for a connection. Along with this process there are several other important and vital processes which should be running. 

Is your database installed *locally* on your machine you are connecting from? If it isn't - there won't be those processes running.

Comment: @OraNob No. DB is somewhere else but somehow Toad manages to connect. I wonder how. I have listed all processed with `WMIC` but no process has "Oracle" or "lsnr". How does Toad manage to connect?

Comment: You are not understanding the architecture of an Oracle database OR understanding the principles of an Oracle client / Oracle server connection. Unless you have access to the server itself - you will not be able to list or see the Oracle processes - you are running as a client.

I would invest some time into reading about Oracle database architecture - otherwise you will find everything else to which follows from a connection - difficult.

Comment: As client you do not need OracleService, only an instant client and if you can connect from Toad, you have it. On command line write "sqlplus" followed of the connect string. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm