# ORA-12560: TNS:Protocal adaper error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to oracle. I am getting an `ORA-12560: TNS:Protocol adapter error.`, when I am trying to connect to an Oracle 11g database. But the all services are running.

Comment: Please share your connection string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error see if this help