# TNS protocol adapter error on test environment

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, toad, tnsnames

I have been stuck with an error "TNS PROTOCOL ADAPTER ERROR". My toad seems to be connecting fine with all environments like 'test1', 'test2', 'dev1', 'prod', but, when I try and connect to 'test2' environment using visual studio, I am getting the error. It is able to connect to other environments but failing on 'test2'. I tried my best, but wasn't able to get through it. The TNSNAMES file also seems fine, please help.

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug? Did you search Google? There are numerous hits for it including one to this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error)

Comment: I tried all of them ,  but none of them seems to work, i am having trouble only in one of the environments , but not all of them , the visual studio was able to connect to other envirnoments, for example, the connectionstring in web config, '/....../BSIHELPERSERVICEdev' would connect to dev,/..../ BSIHELPERSERVICEUAT would connect to uat, i am having issue connecting to one of the envirnoments