# Connection failure with Oracle DB in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish-4

I opened a database through glassfish4 server but When I want to access database with Intellij Idea I get these errors:

[image]

Settings in Glassfish:

[image]

Comment: try "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe"

Comment: there's nothing new  :(

Comment: check error message, it should give you some though what is wrong

Comment: How can find error message in files ?

Comment: At the bottom of the "Screenshot intellij idea" I can see Error warning.

Comment: just one error : Error: Connection to @localhost failed.Problem section is empty.

Comment: even if you click on view?

Comment: try to look at oraclexe installation folder. there should be some log file. If you find some error description put it there (without this we can just guessing what is wrong).

Comment: Connection to @localhost failed.
[08006][17002] IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: try to check if tnslistener port number matches 1521 (oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN)

Comment: also make sure, oraclexe is running [how to start oracle server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error#answer-6904462)

Comment: Oracle server running automatically when glassfish run ?

Comment: no, but if you want to connect to oracle db at localhost, it has to run.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484292/how-to-fix-ora-12705-cannot-access-nls-data-files-or-invalid-environment-speci