# How to fix 'ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified'

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an error trying to connect to oracle database:

```
Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [12705] [72000]: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
ORA-02063: preceding line
```

My platform is a MacOs running obviously over a Mac, try to connect to remote oracle database. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700330/ora-12705-cannot-access-nls-data-files-or-invalid-environment

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using SQL Developer you have to follow this steps:

1. Open SQL Developer package content. Go to Applications, right click on SQL Developer and select "Show Package Contents".
2. Go to `Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/`
3. Open `sqldeveloper.conf` using a text editor.
4. Add the following lines:

```
# Options to avoid "ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified."
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
AddVMOption -Duser.region=US
AddVMOption -Duser.country=en
```

5. Restart SQL Developer

Answer (score 9):

If you are here and using any on the Jetbrain Products (Pycharm/IntellJ IDEA/DataGrip)

1. Open the properties of the connection
2. Under **Advanced**, add the line below in the VM Options (without any quotes)

-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US

[image: Screen shot of the settings path]

Answer (score 1):

With Maven try to add parameters:

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **oracle instant client** for windows then **remove** the **NSL variable** from the windows environment, your issue will be resolved.