# How to restart an oracle 11g database in windows 10 machine

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, database-administration

Accidently killed the oracle 11g process via task manager.
Sql plus login throws error
**ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error)

Answer (score 2):

Log in with SQLPlus as sys using this command:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

then shutdown the database using this command:

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
```

then startup the instance, mount the database, and open the database with this command:

```
STARTUP;
```