# Error- pl/sql developer -12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, plsql, connection, plsqldeveloper, tns

Good Morning. I tell you my connection problem with pl / sql Developer.

First, I will indicate my environment:
-SO Windows10 64 bits.
-PLSQL Developer 13 (64 bit)
-Client Oracle 12-64bits.

Now I put the screenshots of my settings.

[image: preferences connection]

[image]

[image: system file directory]

[image]

[image: When I want to connect Pl / SQl developer finds the file now because I get my connection name: 'exadata']

But finally the connection error message returns

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cause of this issue would be you tried to connect to `Oracle`, but the service name is either missing from the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file or is incorrectly defined.

You can try below options:

1. Make sure that the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file exists and is in the correct directory.
2. Make sure that the `service name` that you are connecting to is included in the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file and that it is correctly defined.
3. Make sure that there are no syntax errors in the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file. For example, if there are unmatched parentheses in the file (ie: open bracket without the corresponding close bracket), the file will be rendered unusable.
4. Check if `tnsping` works. Open command window type tnsping `SERVICE_NAME`. Here `SERVICE_NAME` is the oracle database you want to connect to and it must already exist in `tnsnames.ora` file where your client product is installed.
5. If `tnsping` works and still `PL/SQL` Developer complains about `ORA-12154` then check where `PL/SQL` Developer program is installed. If it is located in an address which contains brackets this is the problem. So uninstall and reinstall it in a location where location address doesn't contain brackets.
6. set Environment Variables: `ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID`

I hope this works with the above options

Comment: Good morning. Thank you very much Andrew.
The first three points I have verified are correct. I have checked the connection with the sqldeveloper and it works correctly.

I tried throwing the statement: tnsping <service_name> but it gives me an error again:


"tnsping" is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: you have not set environment path variable..may be thats the issue is for your connection...you need to set the envíronment path variable for example something like this SET path=c:\oracle\product\10.1.0\db_1\bin

Comment: this post has everything mentioned you can refer this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread, but in case anyone is still struggling with it.
I just reformatted my TNS and it is working now.

Previously:

```
DBXXXX = (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS) (HOST = somehostname) (POST=1523))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = some.service.name)
)
(SECURITY = (SSL....))
)
```

Now:

```
DBXXXX = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS) (HOST = somehostname) (POST=1523))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = some.service.name))
    (SECURITY = (SSL....))
)
```

Done that for *all* connections in the TNSNAMES.ora file and it is working now.