# Oracle: I'm getting 'ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error' when I try to log onto Oracle

Tags: oracle, error-handling, sqlplus

I am getting the `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error` when I try to log onto Oracle. Everyplace I have looked to fix this issue says I need to change something in Services.msc, but when I go there, I'm not finding any of the oracle services that I'm supposed to be changing.

[image]

I have found absolutely no fix for this issue and after several hours, I'm hoping you guys can maybe see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error)

Comment: What piece of software are you running? As you say, none of the expected Oracle services appear in your service list. What version of the Oracle database do you have installed on your PC?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - I have Oracle SQL*Plus v19.3 (sqldeveloper-19.4.0.354.1759-x64)

Comment: @KenWhite - No. That was one of the ones I saw, and it wants me to change the Services.msc which isn't there.

Comment: @MakPo: Oracle SQL *Plus is a query and management tool. AFAIK, it does not install the Oracle database server. That's a separate installation. That would explain why you don't have the services available - you haven't installed the actual Oracle product yet.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer is just a query tool. [The Oracle database is a separate product that you need to install](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html)