# HELPP -- Cannot start OracleServiceORCL

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle19c, dataguard, ora-12560

It's my first time asking a question here but I wanted to log with username and password on SQL*Plus and it's giving me this error 
**ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error**. 
After I googled for it found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904462/13486606) answer and I tried to Start **OracleServiceORCL** but it gives me another error saying 
**Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.** The image -> [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCxyC.png)

Any ides on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you got an Oracle instance set up on this machine? The service name for it will be “OracleService<SID>”, if you’re unsure what you called it when you created it you can just look at the services that do exist

Comment: Run services.msc and give us a screen dump of the services that start with "Oracle". That will help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

You might try sqlplus user/password@localhost:1521/orcl