# How to connect with oracle database?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am using this code to connect with oracle database:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn_str = u"jbdc:oracle:thin:@****_***.**.com"
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

How can I resolve it?

Thank you

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a JDBC thin connect string to connect with cx_Oracle (or the new [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb)). You must use either an alias found in a tnsnames.ora file, or the full connect descriptor (such as that found in a tnsnames.ora) file or an EZ+ Connect string. An example follows:

```py
conn_str = "user/password@host:port/service_name"
```

With the new python-oracledb driver you can also do this:

```py
import oracledb
conn = oracledb.connect(user="USER", password="PASSWORD", host="my_host",
                        port=1521, service_name="my_service")
```

See the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find tnsnames.ora for SQL Squirrel?

Comment: The environment variable $TNS_ADMIN points to the location of that file, or it is found in certain default locations. The documentation link I gave above shows this. Here is a more direct link: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optnetfiles